# How to properly create regular expressions in Jest moduleNameMapper

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am trying to test a Vue CLI project with `vue-test-utils` and Jest. I am using some icons from [`vue-material-design-icons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-material-design-icons), but they are not getting transformed when I run Jest. This is the error that I get when I run Jest:

```
    /path/to/node_modules/vue-material-design-icons/Sitemap.vue:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest) 
    {<template functional>
     ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

      101 | <script>
      102 | import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";
    > 103 | import SitemapIcon from "vue-material-design-icons/Sitemap.vue";
          | ^
      104 | import AccessPointIcon from "vue-material-design-icons/AccessPoint.vue";
      105 | import AlphaIcon from "vue-material-design-icons/Alpha.vue";
      106 |
```

After reading the README on the [`jest-transform-stub`](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/jest-transform-stub#faq) GitHub page, I tried to stub out the `vue-material-design-icons` in my `jest.config.js` file with this configuration:

```
...
moduleNameMapper: {
  "/vue-material-design-icons\/[\w]+.vue/": "jest-transform-stub",
  "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
},
...
```

...but it is not working. I have tested the regular expression in both https://regex101.com/ and https://www.regextester.com/ and the regular expression works as expected in both sites.

If I hard code the file path into the config, then it works:

```
...
moduleNameMapper: {
  "vue-material-design-icons/Sitemap.vue": "jest-transform-stub",
  "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
},
...
```

Obviously I don't want to hard code the file path for every icon in the project, though.

Does anyone know why the regular expression is not working?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. First, this is what my `moduleNameMapper` config now looks like in `jest.config.js`:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "^vue-material-design-icons\/[a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.vue$": "jest-transform-stub",
  "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
},
```

This regular expression will now match any `vue-material-design-icons/IconName.vue` imports in your code files:

`^vue-material-design-icons\/[a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.vue$`

Jest's documentation for the `moduleNameMapper` config object states "If you provide module name without boundaries `^$` it may cause hard to spot errors." (See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string.)

So I wrapped the RegEx in between a caret `^` and a dollar sign `$` (instead of in between two forward slashes `/`) and everything works now.

NOTE: The `jest-transform-stub` module is a simple module that "you can use ... to avoid errors when importing non JavaScript assets" (https://github.com/eddyerburgh/jest-transform-stub).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I ignored the transformed patterns of the components which were not getting transformed ('vue-material-design-icons' and 'vue-simple-spinner' in this example)

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!vue-material-design-icons|vue-simple-spinner)"
],
```